# Github pre-commit enforce commit message to contains a specific message

Tags: github, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I hope this question won't sound silly but I am really curious and confused at the same time.

I have been reading different documentation and watched different videos but none of them was satisfying enough.

I have different GitHub repository linked with Azure Boards. Azure board GitHub integration, allow me to see the commits done on a specific task on azure board if the commit message is done in the following way:

```
commit-message AB#ticket-id
```

This is just perfect and works just fine, but I have been looking into GitHub pre-commit to enforce a `commit-message` to contain the `AB#ticket-id` and if it doesn't, to block the commit.

The final result that I am looking for is as follow.

If I commit this `initial commit` and try to push, I want to get an error or something to block me.

But if I commit this `Initial Commit AB#0001` to be able to push that commit to the repo.

What I am looking for is just to look for the commit if container `AB#int`

I hope I explained clearly my point and please if you need more infos just let me know.

Thank you so much for your time and any help/explaination you can provide

Comment: I believe you're looking for the [`commit-msg` git hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_commit_msg)

Comment: @AnthonySottile Thank you so much for your reply. I was watching some of your videos to see if I could find an answer to my dilemma. I will try to give a shot to the `commit-msg` as you advised and see what I can figure out. Thank you so much for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `commit-msg` hook on your local system to perform this linting for you if you like.  However, these hooks can be bypassed with `--no-verify` without leaving any trace, so if you're working on a project with multiple people, you need to do something different.  In addition, this kind of hook can be very irritating for people who use squash or fixup commits, so you'd want to make it optional.

If you want to implement an effective control, [the Git FAQ is clear](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#restrict-with-hooks): you need to either use a `pre-receive` hook or a CI check.  If you're using github.com, `pre-receive` hooks aren't allowed, so you'll need to implement this check in your CI.